# Merging to a branch that a file name was changed and the old name is using in the pulled branch

Tags: git

I have a master branch. There I have a file called "a". I add and commit the file. Then I create a branch called "f-a". I create a file there called "f-a" in this file I include the "a" file which was created during the master branch. Add and commit those changes. Meanwhile, some other developer renamed "a" file in his own branch and merged back to the master branch.
I then move back to the master branch and merge the f-a branch into it. Boom I include the "a" file which is now called... mmm lets say... "B".

Is there a way to resist this kind of problem?

Comment: Does rebasing on master fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Git has an option when rebasing or merging, called `find-renames`.

> Detect renames. If n is specified, it is a threshold on the similarity index (i.e. amount of addition/deletions compared to the file’s size). For example, -M90% means Git
>              should consider a delete/add pair to be a rename if more than 90% of the file hasn’t changed. Without a % sign, the number is to be read as a fraction, with a decimal point
>              before it. I.e., -M5 becomes 0.5, and is thus the same as -M50%. Similarly, -M05 is the same as -M5%. To limit detection to exact renames, use -M100%. The default similarity
>              index is 50%.

So you can try to merge into master with

```
git rebase --strategy-option="find-renames=20" master
```

This will set the threshold to 20% when detecting renames upon rebasing onto master branch, where a similarity of 20% would consider two files the same and do a rename.